# First mean value theorem for definite integrals and differentiation

Tags: derivatives, leibniz-integral-rule, mean-value-theorem

From the First MVT for integral we have ($g$ with constant sign) $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)\,dx=f(c)\int _{a}^{b}g(x)\,dx.$.
My question: is there a theorem that tells how to sign $\frac{dc}{db}$. Is the below differentiation, using Leibniz rule, correct ?
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d}{db}\left( \int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)\,dx\right)  &=&f\left( b\right)
g\left( b\right)  \\
&=&\frac{dc}{db}f^{\prime }(c)\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\,dx+f(c)g(b)
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dc}{db}=\frac{\left[ f\left( b\right) -f(c)\right] g(b)}{f^{\prime
}(c)\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\,dx}
\end{equation*}

Comment: $c$ is not necessarily unique, so not necessarily a function of $b$.
And even, if $c$ is a function of $b$, it's not necessarily differentiable.

Comment: Thanks Essaidi, I was aware of this but if $f,g$ are continuous and monotone functions?